# Testing styled-components when referencing to other component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

I am having an issue trying to test a component made with styled-components.

so i have two components and i am trying to get the second component's background color to change if i hover on the first element.

My components:

```
const Container = styled.div``

const Label = styled.label`
     ${Container}:hover & {
            background-color: red;
     }
`
```

Whenever i try to test the label component with jest `expect(label).toHaveStyle()` it always throws an error that said  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null`. But when i commented the reference to container component within label the test passes. Can anybody help? Thank you sooo much.

I am using react-testing-library to render my components in my test files.

Comment: Please provide more information on how you're rendering the component in your test file.

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten the code in a sandbox and everything works just fine . Maybe i made the wrong implementation in my project. Thanks for the help!

sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-hodgkin-irruc?file=/src/App.js